# $C[0,1], 0<p<1$ is not a norm linear space. What about $p = \infty$ (i.e. supremum norm)?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

To Prove - $C[0,1], 0<p<1$ (with usual p-norm) is not a norm linear space.

My thought process - I know that the triangle inequality is violated. But I am not able to produce a counterexample because every time I try to construct an example, I violate that it must be continuous on $[0,1]$. 
One more subtle point, most other similar proofs that I've done usually are with the $f = g$(or $x = y$ for the two points of Triangle Inequality). But here, taking $f = g$ will not provide a counterexample since for such a case, Triangle Inequality holds with equality.

To prove/disprove -  $C[0,1], $p =  inifinity$ $ (i.e. the norm defined the supremum of the absolute value of the function on the closed interval $[0,1]$.) is not a norm linear space.

My thought process - The proof for p>=1 uses Holder Inequality, Minkowski Inequality. I wish to know if that thing can simply be used for p = infinity also. Then, that's done.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Can you write down exactly the norms you are talking about, and the precise statement(s) you are trying to (dis)prove?

Comment: @NateEldredge, p norm is the integration over the interval [0,1] , of the p the power of the absolute value of the function, this whole integral made to the power 1/p. Also, the p = infinity norm is the supremum of the absolute value of the function on the interval [0,1].

Comment: @ChahatChawla Take whatever counterexample you've come up with, and tweak it very slightly, and you'll have a continuous function.